# Can my RCL (Razor Class Library) override another RCL shared partial view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know in the **end project**, I can always override a view or partial view provided by an RCL but I didn't know another RCL cannot do that. Here's my situation now:

- `WebCommon` RCL provides `_SharedContent.cshtml` partial view. It also has `_Layout_Shared` that renders `_SharedContent.cshtml`.
- `WebCommon.Theme` RCL depends on WebCommon (refer to it). It further extends features to `WebCommon`. Here, I try to provide its own `_SharedContent.cshtml`.
- `MyWebsite` refers to `WebCommon.Theme`.

If `MyWebsite` provides its own `_SharedContent.cshtml`, it works fine. Even `_Layout_Shared` (from `WebCommon`) has the overridden content. **However**, `_SharedContent.cshtml` from `WebCommon.Theme` is in no way accessible.

I have control of all the projects. Is there anyway I can make `WebCommon.Theme`'s `_SharedContent.cshtml` so I do not have to copy its content to every of `MyWebsite`?

Note that I can name it `_SharedContent_Theme.cshtml` but then `_Layout_Shared` from `WebCommon` does not know it.